# emacs 23 on OS X: how to open web links from emacs?

Tags: emacs, emacs23, carbon-emacs

I'm trying the 23.2 release Cocoa Emacs build (OS X 10.6). There's a
number of things that are more annoying about Cocoa Emacs than the
terrific Carbon Emacs (based on an Emacs 22 build, I believe), so I
hoped folks might have some solutions/thoughts (unfortunately posting
on neither the carbon-emacs list nor emacs-dev has produced a useful
reply, so I thought I'd try Stack Overflow for the first time):

- I used to be able to option-click (in my mailer) on web links, but
  that doesn't work any more. This might be mailer-specific, but I
  don't think so; I think it used to map to middle-button, but it
  doesn't any more. What is the current keyboard equivalent for middle-button (and
  will this work for launching web links?)? I should note browse-url
  called manually works just fine, so this is a question of "how can
  I map option-click or some other mouse equivalent to browse-url"?

Comment: You might have better luck editing this to one question and open two more new questions for the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`goto-address`](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/cgi-comment/info2html?%28emacs%29Goto-address) perhaps is what you want.

```
  (add-hook 'find-file-hook 'goto-address-mode)
```

Comment: Fantastic! That's spot on. For me, (add-hook 'wl-message-redisplay-hook 'goto-address) gets the job done. Many thanks.